# Moving site to a new server

Tags: server-migration

Whats the deal to moving a site to a new server? I saved all of my templates as files. And I have datagrab so I can import the entries. I've also grabbed all the plugins.

But do I have to recreate the whole internal structure of the site (channels, fields, etc.)? If so OMG...

Answer (score 2):

No, you should just have to move your Database and template files to the new server.

---

MODERATOR EDIT

**LINK TO EE DOCS**
[Moving ExpressionEngine to Another Server](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html)

Comment: So install ee then import db?

Comment: Move all your files over (no installing anything) then import your database file to your mysql manager. Then use a plugin like reelocate http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate

Comment: All else fails, read the documentation http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

Comment: @therooster Yes, thats all you should have to do to move your EE site. Also, remember to backup all your files.

Comment: I followed all of the instructions. imported my old db on new server. grab all the folders. updated the config and db file as necessary. now I'm getting the follow error:  An "Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: account/login.php"    ....any ideas... i reuploaded my cp default theme but still no go.

Comment: just a quick bump to see if any one has an idea...

Comment: If you're getting any errors about missing files, I'd suggest reuploading ALL files again.

Answer (score 0):

after trying everything, i blew away the files and reuploaded. now all works.